# Echo em tempo real

Tags: php

Como que eu posso exibir o que foi digitado em um campo `<input />` ou `<textarea>` em tempo real em PHP, igual este do Stack-Overflow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com o php não tem como fazer isso "em tempo real". O PHP é uma linguagem server-side (processa as coisas do lado do servidor), que enviará uma saída de dados para o cliente (navegador).

Depois que essa saída ocorre, o que pode ser feito é usar Javascript para realizar tal operação.

Veja:

```js
window.onload = function () {
     
  function qs(el){
    return document.querySelector(el);
  }
  
  var saida = qs('#saida');
  
  qs('#texto').addEventListener('input', function () {
      saida.innerHTML = this.value;  
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="saida"></div>
<textarea id="texto"></textarea>
```

Nesse caso, eu usei o evento `input`para capturar o que é digitado no `textarea` e, em seguida, passá-lo para o html. Mas você pode usar `keyup`.

**Atenção**: para evitar a injeção de HTML no código, ao invés de usar `innerHTML`, use `innerText`.

```js
window.onload = function () {
     
  function qs(el){
    return document.querySelector(el);
  }
  
  var saida = qs('#saida');
  
  qs('#texto').addEventListener('input', function () {
      saida.innerText = this.value;  
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="saida"></div>
<textarea id="texto"></textarea>
```

Comment: Perfeito @Wallace , obrigado onde posso achar documentações de java para iniciar estudo sobre a mesma ?!

Comment: Java é diferente de Javascript, jovem. Não confunda as coisas.

Comment: Aqui dá para aprender muita coisa: http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: Perfeito obrigado hein :D